# Magento, get "new" or "edit" during product creation or editing

Tags: magento, url, product

In Magento, while I'm creating or editing a product, I need to know if this product is a new product or an edited one.

I found a part or the URL with "new" or "edit", but I didn't found anything online to help me catching this.

Can you help me?

EDIT:

Okay I found something:
I'm trying to get ActionName of the controller, but I'm on the Block who runs the Custom Options Tab while creating or editing a product. So when I get ActionName, I get "options", it's the child, I need the ActionName above (it might be a parent ?).
Any help is welcome to do that, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the creation of a product the product_id is NULL, if it's an existing product then the product_id will be greater than zero.

Comment: Oh thank you, I missed this point, this is pretty obvious BTW.